# How to compare the colums (2nd and 3rd) of 2 .csv files based on a condition in matlab or octave

Tags: matlab, csv, octave, multiple-columns, file-comparison

I have a program based on some functionality and the results are displayed on 2 .csv files (file1 and file2)
The files consist of same rows and columns, the columns are named as condition, supply1, supply2
I want to read both the files into the program, load them and then compare the contents of supply1, supply2, based on the condition and number.
We have to compare the respective contents and display the difference of supply1 and suppy2 between those 2 files.
Eg: condition ta and number 1 of the 4th row of file1 has to compare with condition ta and number 1 of the 1st row of file2
Please help me on this.

file 1
[file 1 contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccTbH.jpg)

[file 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8lMv.jpg)

Comment: What is your problem ? Where are you stuck ? Please post your code to show us what you've already done.

Comment: file1 = fopen ( 'file1.csv' );
file2 = fopen ( 'file2.csv' ); 
data1 = textscan (file1, "%s,%f,%f,%d \n" , "HeaderLines" , 1, "Delimiter" , "," )
data2 = textscan (file2, "%s,%f,%f,%d \n" , "HeaderLines" , 1, "Delimiter" , "," );
fclose (file1);
fclose (file2);

I have extratced all the data but now I don't know how to compare since It has string values

Comment: Please add updates and clarifications (**especially** code) to your question using [edit]. So your problem is comparing strings? How exactly do you want to compare them? For equality? Lexicographic ordering? Length?

Comment: add also example of data and of the expected comparison result